# Nested If in Iterative Template Evaluated Despite First If Returning False

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using an iterative template to total up a count of elements where I couldn't see a cleaner way to manage. However, the nested if is being evaluated despite the initial if statement evaluating as false.

This code snippet is not elegant, but shows what I'm dealing with. The test variable should come back with a number, but is instead returning an empty value. I've tracked the variables with debugger and everything is fine until the last evaluation (i.e., when typeCount is greater than typeTotal). At that point the position() = typeCount is being evaluated and resetting the rowCount.

As far as I can see there is no reason for the second If to be evaluated if the first one failed. Therefore the result generated by the last iteration should be returned to the test variable.

I'm running this in OxygenML using the Saxon-PE 9.7.0.19 processor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="contractTypeCount" select="count(distinct-values(costDefinitions/cost/contract/contractType/@printcode))"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="test">
            <xsl:call-template name="typeGrouping">
                <xsl:with-param name="rowCount" select="0"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="typeCount" select="1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="typeTotal" select="$contractTypeCount"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:value-of select="concat('Count:',$test)"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="typeGrouping">
        <xsl:param name="typeCount"/>
        <xsl:param name="rowCount"/>
        <xsl:param name="typeTotal"/>

        <xsl:if test="$typeCount &lt;= $typeTotal">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="/costDefinitions/cost/contract/contractType" group-by="@printcode">
                <xsl:sort select="@printcode" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = $typeCount">
                    <xsl:variable name="typeTemp" select="@printcode"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="countTemp" select="count(distinct-values(/costDefinitions/cost[contract/contractType/@printcode = $typeTemp]/creditor/@printcode))"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="typeGrouping">
                        <xsl:with-param name="typeCount" select="$typeCount + 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="rowCount" select="$rowCount + $countTemp"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="typeTotal" select="$typeTotal"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XML snippet I'd expect the return to be 5: Purchase = 3 and Barter = 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<costDefinitions>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="ABCD"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="ABCD"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Barter"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="ABCD"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="ABCD"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="KMNO"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Barter"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="KMNO"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="KMNO"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="KMNO"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="STUV"/>
    </cost>
    <cost>
        <contract>
            <contractType printcode="Purchase"/>
        </contract>
        <creditor printcode="STUV"/>
    </cost>
</costDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really looking into why your XSLT was not giving you the desired result, because there is actually a simpler way to do this. You can get the distinct count like so:

```
 <xsl:variable name="contractTypeCount" 
               select="count(distinct-values(costDefinitions/cost/concat(contract/contractType/@printcode, '|', creditor/@printcode)))"/>
```

So, this variable should contain "5" as desired.

Comment: That variable does indeed produce the result, which is excellent. Now I'm curious why the IF was evaluating the way it was. I want to understand where the code was tripping up in case I have to do some silly iterative template like that again.

Comment: Looking at it in more detail now, your template does not actually output anything. It does a `xsl:for-each-group`,sets some variables, and conditionally calls the template again, but there is no `xsl:value-of` or `xsl:copy-of`, so nothing is effectively "returned" by the template.